# Returning a sorted list within function....only returns one value when list is printed all values displayed

Tags: python, list, sorting, return

I am computing a simple recommendation system. In my nearest neighbor equation, I am trying to return the list all_combinations so that it is sorted.

When the list is printed within the function, all values appear when the program is run. However, the return value (the sorted list) does not appear.

Only one value appears and what is even weirder is that this value changes each time the program is run.

It returns any one of the values within the list.

What's going on here? I have tried moving the return statement to different tab levels, and it doesn't change how it operates.

The code:

```
#find the nearest neighbor 
def nearestNeighborManhattan(username,users):
    distances = 0
    all_combinations = []
    for name in users:
        if name != username:
            distances = sum_manhattan(users[username],users[name])
            all_combinations.append(distances)
            print(all_combinations)
            neat = all_combinations.sort()

            return neat 


print(nearestNeighborManhattan("Veronica",users))
```

and the output is this when return is commented out:

```
[3.5]
[3.5, 8.5]
[3.5, 8.5, 4.0]
[3.5, 4.0, 8.5, 4.0]
[3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 8.5, 6.5]
[3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 6.5, 8.5, 4.0]
[3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 6.5, 8.5, 2.0]
```

the value when the return statement is not commented out and the print statement is not commented out either changes each time the program is run, to one of the numbers within the list. The last time I ran it it was 8.5, and only 8.5. The list does not print at all.

P.S. in the print statement outside the function "Veronica" is simply a user within the dictionary I am working with.

Comment: I think the return neat should be in line with for loop, therefore you could loop through all the date then return

Answer (score 1):

`neat = all_combinations.sort()` sets `neat` to `None` because `sort` sorts in place (and returns `None`).

If you want `neat` to be a sorted version of `all_combinations`, use `neat = sorted(all_combinations)`

Comment: doing this and moving return to for loop worked, thanks!